# Accessibility - Provide descriptive text in label elements

Tags: checkbox, label, accessibility

I have a toggle checkbox enclosed inside a label element. However, I don't need any text to a label element. But accessibility throws me an error to add a label text which I don't need at all. How do I overcome this error?

```
<label class="toggle"  for="togglechkbox" id="Remember My ID" >
    <input id="togglechkbox" name="togglechkbox" type="checkbox" >
</label>
```

Comment: What error? and which screen reader you are using?

Comment: How do sighted users know what that checkbox is for?

Comment: Why do you provide a `label` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Although technically valid from W3C point of view, it has never been very recommended to nest an `<input>` inside a `<label>`.
It is often said that some screen reader / browser combinations don't support it. It's perhaps the reason you obtain warnings from your validation tool.
It would be safer to put the label immediately before or immediately after the checkbox.

Now to answer a bit more generally to the question, you must provide a label, otherwise screen reader users don't know what the checkbox is for, i.e. they are unable to know what does the checkbox.
Alternatively you can remove the label but compensate with aria-label and/or aria-labelledby.

You must do one or the other. Otherwise it isn't screen reader accessible.

Comment: why did you revert the code markup? It is required to see the html code you inserted in your post. Without the code syntax highlight your sentence doesn't make any sense, because stackoverflow is removing the html elements...

Comment: It seems that I have understood your modification in reverse. I didn't remember that my post had this problem. It was unclear, but that's the fault of the site, not yours. If your modification is only to make my HTML code appear, you can do it. I'm sorry. Thank you.

Comment: [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse) doesn't like `<label>` elements for buttons, unfortunately.

Comment: doesn't like <label> elements for buttons, unfortunately. => No, because buttons should normally contain their own accessible text; they don't need additional label.